# What's the difference of creating new column between df.with_column and df['new_col'] = func(df['old_col']) in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Sorry if this question's asked before, but I've never seen it yet.

I realised `Polars` can create a new column with

```py
def func(series):
   """sample function """
   return series

df.with_column(
   pl.lit(func(df['old_col'])).alias('new_col')
)
```

yet, it also can be written as:

```
df['new_col'] = func(df['old_col'])
```

Is this performance related?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive my long answer in advance.  But I want to show the benefits and reasons why coding "the Polars way" is worth the learning curve - to achieve the **shockingly** fast performance that we Polars users have come to expect.

##### Transliterated Pandas-style coding

The following code, for lack of a better term, is "transliterated Pandas" code.

```py
df['new_col'] = func(df['old_col'])
```

That is, it resembles Pandas-style code.  And it certainly runs in Polars.  It may even yield acceptable performance in some situations.

But it doesn't embrace **the Polars way** of expressing your calculations so that the Polars engine can easily parallelize computations across multiple cores.  Nor does this code allow for query optimization in `Lazy` mode.  (Indeed, the use of a Python function likely will subject the code to the Python GIL, forcing code to run in single-threaded fashion.)

Most who use Polars have come to expect **much** better performance than single-threaded Python bytecode performance.  (Indeed, that's the entire point of Polars.)

#### An Example

Let's take a closer look.  Let's use the following dataset. Set `nbr_obs` high enough to challenge your system.

```py
import polars as pl

nbr_obs = 1_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'date1': pl.repeat('2001-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date2': pl.repeat('2002-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date3': pl.repeat('2003-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date4': pl.repeat('2004-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date5': pl.repeat('2005-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
    }
)
```

```
shape: (1000000, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ date1      ┆ date2      ┆ date3      ┆ date4      ┆ date5      │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

##### Transliterated Pandas-style code

Now let's create a Python function to parse these dates.

```py
from datetime import datetime
def parse_it(series):
    return [datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d") for date_str in series]
```

And let's run this using "transliterated Pandas" code.  Depending on your OS, watch the CPU usage on your machine as this code runs.

```py
df['date1_parse'] = parse_it(df['date1'])
df['date2_parse'] = parse_it(df['date2'])
df['date3_parse'] = parse_it(df['date3'])
df['date4_parse'] = parse_it(df['date4'])
df['date5_parse'] = parse_it(df['date5'])
```

What do you observe?  You should observe **painfully** single-threaded performance.  (Polars users avoid this **at all costs**, especially since many of us are using large datasets and multi-core computing platforms.)

##### The loss of Lazy Mode

Now, let's try to switch to Polars `Lazy` mode so that we can harness Polars' powerful query optimization engine.

```py
df = df.lazy()
df['date1_parse'] = parse_it(df['date1'])
```

```
>>> df['date1_parse'] = parse_it(df['date1'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'LazyFrame' object is not subscriptable
```

Oops, we cannot use transliterated Pandas-style code in `Lazy` mode.  That's a big loss of potential performance, in general.

##### The Polars Way

The way to harness Polars' powerful engine is to master the [Expression](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expression.html) syntax.  We code our goals in terms of Expressions.  If done well, Polars can parallelize our code (and avoid the Python GIL).  The result is **shockingly** better performance.

Now, let's recreate our dataset, and parse dates using Polars Expressions.  Notice that I've abandoned using a Python function altogether, and have stayed "inside the Polars API".  That is, I've expressed everything I need using Expressions.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'date1': pl.repeat('2001-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date2': pl.repeat('2002-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date3': pl.repeat('2003-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date4': pl.repeat('2004-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
        'date5': pl.repeat('2005-01-01', nbr_obs, eager=True),
    }
)

df.with_columns([
    pl.col("^date.*$").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
])
```

```
shape: (1000000, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ date1      ┆ date2      ┆ date3      ┆ date4      ┆ date5      │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 ┆ 2002-01-01 ┆ 2003-01-01 ┆ 2004-01-01 ┆ 2005-01-01 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

This time, what did you notice about the performance?  **Massively parallel**.  And **shocking** performance.

Does this (long-winded) answer provide some insight as why it's best to master the Expressions syntax, and avoid "transliterated Pandas-style" code?

You can find more information in the [Polars Cookbook](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/expressions.html).  There are lots of great examples of using Expressions and coding "the Polars way".

Comment: Thank you so much for this very infomative answer. I really appreciate your effort and your team! It's true for the learning curve of Polars, but comparing with the performance, it's worth.

Comment: I myself am just a member of the Polars user community.  (The credit for Polars goes to @ritchie46 and his team.)  Nonetheless, there are a lot of us willing to help new users.